# An Animated Image Not Painted Anymore Since Codename One Version 3.3

Tags: codenameone

My app has an animated Image set as icon of a Label instance.
Since Version 3.3 the image is not painted any more. However the animated() methos ist still called and returns true.

Is that caused by "performance improvements"?
What can I do about it?

Comment: I looked into com.codename1.ui.Label.paint(Graphics). There the method com.codename1.ui.Image.getImage() is called which, in my case, returns null. Perhaps I should return something - what?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the correct measure:
Now my animated image class overrides com.codename1.ui.Image.getImage() and returns the result of getImage() of an Image instance created using com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(int, int, int) which I previously only used in my method which overrode com.codename1.ui.Image.drawImage(Graphics, Object, int, int).
Now apparently drawImage() isn't called anymore, but the getImage() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing your own custom subclass of image that relies on draw image?

If so you need to override `requiresDrawImage` in that [Image](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html) subclass as such to disable the performance optimizations in drawing this image:

```
@Override
public boolean requiresDrawImage() {
    return true;
}
```